# web page is downloaded instead of being rendered in safari

Tags: python, django, safari

As the title suggests, when visit my website on safari, web pages are downloaded instead of being rendered normally. Its fine on chrome and firefox. I suspect that the cause of this is `redirect` because it was working on safari when there was no redirect. `/admin` works fine in safari. Please help.

in root/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/albums/latest/', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^albums/', include('photography.urls')),
)
```

in app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'photography.views',

    url(r'^latest/$', views.latest_album),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', views.photos_by_location,
    name='photos_by_location'),

    )
```

and in views.py

```
def latest_album(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    try:
        latest_album = Album.objects.latest('id')
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Didnt find any Album matches the query.")
    photos = get_list_or_404(Photo, album=latest_album)
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['album'] = latest_album
    context_dict['photos'] = photos

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'photography/photos_by_location.html',
                        context_dict, context)
```

some more info about my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 22:58:36 GMT
Location: http://joyceful.com/albums/latest/
P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: permanent=True ? ... try set it to False and clear session data in browser ...

Comment: @madzohan no that didnt help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `TemplateResponse` to `render_to_response` fixed the problem. not sure why though.